# htaccess resulting in 500 internal error

Tags: php, .htaccess

The below code results in `500 internal error`

```
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^albums/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$view_albums.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^albums/view_photo/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$view_photo.php?uid=$1
```

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file tell you?

Comment: What is your question? [ask]

Comment: You have a syntax error in _all_ rules... The `RewriteRule` requires _two_ arguments, you gave only one. Looks like you (accidentally?) stripped a white space between first and second argument.

Comment: Invalid command 'RewriteBase', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Ah, OK. That actually means that the rewrite module has not been enabled (loaded) into your http server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteBase /www/
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  profile.php?u=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^albums/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  view_albums.php?u=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^albums/view_photo/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  view_photo.php?uid=$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Glad I am able to help you out... please upvote the answer too.